# Regex for substring of string in quotes

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I want to match the word / substring `CODE` as part of string in quotes. Example:

```
text "bla CODE bla" text <- match 'CODE'
text "MYCODE" text <- match 'CODE'
"test_CODE_bla" text <- match 'CODE'
text CODE "text" <- no match
```

But `(?<=")(.*)CODE(.*)(?=")` matches the whole string in quotes, not just the word `CODE`.
But something like `(?<=".*)CODE(?=.*")` does not work. Where's my mistake? 
I'm using Notepad++ Search&Replace with Boost RegEx (kinda similar to Perl Syntax!?).

Link: https://regex101.com/r/zkfRMC/1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/zSe1PC/1)?

Comment: What is the regex engine you are using? .NET?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I'm using Notepad++ which uses Perl Regex.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: No, I only want `CODE` to be the marked result.

Comment: It uses Boost regex, not Perl, if you mean the Search and Replace feature. Do you have many quoted strings per line, or just 1?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It seems you're right. It's one quoted string per line and no nested quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's one quoted string per line and no nested quotation marks.

You may use

```
"[^"\n]*\KCODE(?=[^"\n]*")
```

or even

```
".*?\KCODE(?=.*")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c3zvPi/2)

**Details**:

- `"` - a literal double quote
- `[^"\n]*` - 0+ chars other than `"` and LF
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all the text matched so far
- `CODE` - your required substring
- `(?=[^"\n]*")` - there must be 0+ chars other than `"` and LF and then `"` immediately after the current position.

[image]

Comment: Works flawless, thank you. If it isn't to much of an effort, you're free to include a solution for multiple quoted strings per line - for all those who will come here via Google. No pressure though :)

Comment: That is not easy, and is prone with issues.